# How to use globbing in ssh config to connect via SSH tunnel?

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-networking, ssh-tunnel

[image: Here is the architecture from local host to ServerC1..n]

I have configured `~/.ssh/config` file on localhost:

```
### First jump host. Directly reachable
Host ServerA
    Hostname 10.0.5.101
    User jenny
    IdentityFile /home/admin/.ssh/serverA

### Second jumphost. Only reachable via 10.0.5.101
Host ServerB1
  HostName ServerB1
  User james
  ProxyJump ServerA
  IdentityFile /home/admin/.ssh/james

### Host only reachable via serverA and ServerB1
Host ServerC1
  HostName ServerC1
  User root
  ProxyJump ServerB1
  IdentityFile /home/admin/.ssh/ServerC1
```

I can directly connect to `ServerC1` using `ssh ServerC1` command from `localhost` using the config above.

The issue is that there are many `ServerB's` and each `ServerB` is connected to several `ServerC's`. The private keys are the same for all the Servers so that's not the issue.

From localhost, I want to connect via SSH tunnel to any of ServerC1,2,3..n

ServerA `/etc/hosts` has all the hostname and IPs for ServerB's and each ServerB has IPs of ServerC's in it's `/etc/hosts` file.

Can I use pattern matching in my `localhost's` `~/.ssh/config` file to accomplish this? Currently I am limited to connecting `ServerC1` only because I specifically specified `ServerB1` and `ServerC1`

Comment: Did you even google? Internet has tons of examples, ArchLinux' wiki is a single one to mention.

Comment: This ssh config file was created using an example from google. The pattern matching is not working with multiple jump hosts. Hence, I drew a diagram to illustrate and explain the question.

Comment: @poige I didn't find a single example of pattern matching related to ProxyJump in ArchLinux' wiki. I am not sure where in the wiki you are referring to.

Comment: not necessarily ArchLinux, dude, google around: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host#Dynamic_jump_host_list

Comment: There is nothing about pattern matching for my use case there.

Comment: Last time I checked these two weren't the only sites in internet in regards. ;-P

Comment: You keep providing links and those don't have any solution to this problem. So I am not sure you are linking it. So Regards!

Comment: It's trivial so I'm leaving it as an exercise to the reader. Mutual regards, indeed. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from reddit, the best answer to this problem is configuring the `~/.ssh/config` file as follows: Assuming all of the ServerB* has same IdentityFile.

```
Host ServerA
    Hostname 10.0.5.101
    User jenny
    IdentityFile /home/admin/.ssh/serverA

Match originalhost ServerB*
    User james
    ProxyJump ServerA
    IdentityFile /home/admin/.ssh/james
```

And then at command-line:

`ssh -J serverB1 -i /home/admin/.ssh/ServerC1 root@ServerC1`